# Java equivalent of opencv c++ Mat->data[]

Tags: java, opencv, opacity

I came across this function for overlaying transparent image over background.
https://gist.github.com/maximus5684/082f8939edb6aed7ba0a

it work great in c++. But while converting back into java. i am not able to find equivalent Java call for this particular.

`double opacity = ((double)overlay->data[fY * overlay->step + fX * overlay->channels() + 3]) / 255;`

I am using official Opencv Java binding version 3.1 to convert it to java. 
can anyone guide me in right direction?

Comment: Are you using the official Java bindings? Please specify this in your question, plus the OpenCV version.

Comment: Can you also include the definition of the `overlay` matrix? What are the expected dimensions and value type?

Comment: That just takes value of 4th channel of  `overlay` at position `(fX, fY)`, casts it to double and scales by `1.0/255.0`.

Comment: In Java OpenCV bindings the `Mat` class provides `get` and `put`, so just use those. Reading at least the first few paragraphs of the [`Mat` documentation page](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) should help shed some light on the meaning of that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That use of the OpenCV C++ API would not be very recommended either. You have the template [`Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726) function instead, which allows you to retrieve the value of a particular point of the matrix by reference:

```
double opacity = static_cast<double>(overlay->at<unsigned char>(fy, fx, 3));
```

Since Java does not have pointer arithmetic nor pure references to array elements, the bindings provide `get` and `put` method overloads. If I recall correctly, you should try something like this:

```
double opacity = overlay.get(fy, fx)[3] / 255.;
src.put(y, x, srcPx * (1. - opacity) + overlayPx * opacity);
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. Also Here is the complete conversion if somebody needs it. https://pastebin.com/X3VNqAxA